# Telegraf Tail file that contains json data to Influx

Tags: influxdb, tail, telegraf, telegraf-plugins

How can I extract the json data into influx by tailing a file that has the JSON data?

EG:

My logs are like this:

```
2020-12-01T18:34:06+02:00 10.132.90.194 {"wfd_successful_hits_sec": "0", "sql_hits_sec_max": "0", "timestamp": "2020/12/01 18:34:01", "connection_sec_max": "1922", "http_hits_sec_max": "1106", "http_hits_sec": "106", "wfd_successful_hits_sec_max": "0", "sql_hits_sec": "0", "sql_audit_phase2_events_sec_max": "0", "hdfs_hits_sec": "0", "connection_sec": "26"}
```

Is there a way to just extract the JSON part and send it to influx?

I know the grok pattern `(\{.*\})$` will extract the JSON part.

My config looks like this:

```
[global_tags]
[agent]
  interval = "10s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  hostname = ""
  omit_hostname = false
[[inputs.tail]]
  files = ["/opt/soc/perf_stat/host*log"]
  data_format = "json"
[[outputs.influxdb_v2]]
  urls = ["http://localhost:8086"]
  token = "TOKEN"
  organization = "ORG"
  bucket = "performance_stats
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of configuration parameters you can pass to your input plugin to tell it how to extract fields, tags and the timestamp from your json structure. See https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/parsers/json